# How to remove slashes from a string in c# or how can i create a string which contains double quotes (")

Tags: c#, json, replace, stripslashes

I am struggling with a string

```
"[{\"Item\": { \"Name\": \"item1\" }, \"ShipQuantity\": \" 50.0000000000000000000\", \"Total\": \"10.0000000000000000000\"},{\"Item\": { \"Name\": \"Gratuity\" }, \"ShipQuantity\": \" 1.0000000000000000000\", \"Total\": \"10.0000000000000000000\"}]"
```

i need the string exact like this

```
[{"Item": { "Name": "item1" }, "ShipQuantity": " 50.0000000000000000000", "Total": "10.0000000000000000000"},{"Item": { "Name": "Gratuity" }, "ShipQuantity": " 1.0000000000000000000", "Total": "10.0000000000000000000"}]"
```

But either not able to remove slashes from it, i tried

```
var string = "[{\"Item\": { \"Name\": \"item1\" }, \"ShipQuantity\": \" 50.0000000000000000000\", \"Total\": \"10.0000000000000000000\"},{\"Item\": { \"Name\": \"Gratuity\" }, \"ShipQuantity\": \" 1.0000000000000000000\", \"Total\": \"10.0000000000000000000\"}]";

string = string.Replace(@"\","");
```

But its not replacing it.

Comment: Let me guess: you are inspecting this string in the Visual Studio debugger, which will show the string's escaped form, even though the actual string doesn't contain backslashes.

Comment: Don't forget that if you preview the string in debug mode, it will show you escape slashes. Try to print out the string, it should be correct.

Comment: yes i am debugging it in visual studio, but i am not only debugging it. i am also posting  the data also after string replace. where i am receiving the posted data there also slashes (\) not removed

Comment: Try string contents of `"-\"-"` and inspects it's .Length property - it doesn't count the backslash because it is not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to remove all escape characters from your `JSON` string is to use the `Regex.Unescape()` method. This method returns a new string with no escape characters. Even characters such as `\n` `\t` etc are removed.

Make sure to import the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions

var string = "[{\"Item\": { \"Name\": \"item1\" }, \"ShipQuantity\": \" 50.0000000000000000000\", \"Total\": \"10.0000000000000000000\"},{\"Item\": { \"Name\": \"Gratuity\" }, \"ShipQuantity\": \" 1.0000000000000000000\", \"Total\": \"10.0000000000000000000\"}]";

var unescapedstring = Regex.Unescape(string);
```

More information on this method can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Unescape_System_String_)

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping `"` correctly. There is no issue at all.

```cs
var string = "[{\"Item\": { \"Name\": \"item1\" }, \"ShipQuantity\": \" 50.0000000000000000000\", \"Total\": \"10.0000000000000000000\"},{\"Item\": { \"Name\": \"Gratuity\" }, \"ShipQuantity\": \" 1.0000000000000000000\", \"Total\": \"10.0000000000000000000\"}]";
```

The reason why you are seeing the backsplashes is that you are previewing the output in the debugger, who automatically escapes the double-quotes.

Comment: After replacing the slashed i am posting the data also. The data where i am receiving is not having slashes removed. Its coming there with slashes

Comment: I believe there are no slashes. Print out the string using `Console.WriteLine(string)` for example. If you don't see any slashes in the console, then it is correct. Like most people wrote here, it is due to the debugger preview.